# What exactly is the difference between node vs @node in chef template files

Tags: chef, ruby

I am new to chef and not able to get a hang of the difference between `node` vs `@node` usage in template files. I am not able to find a good documentation around this particular thing. Any explanation or reference to good documentation would be much helpful and appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No difference, mostly. `@node` is a normal template variable that we always pass in for you, while `node` is a template helper method that returns the variable. We recommend not making heavy use of either (manually pass in the data you want to use via the `variables` property) but when you must, use `nodes` for similarity with recipe code.